# Updating an Informix database over ODBC with an object using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to update an object in one shot with Dapper rather than having to write out every variable/field alignment. Here's an example of what I'm doing now, which is to explicitly spell out each field:

```
    public string UpdateAttributes(List<ItemAttribute> attributesList)
    {     
        try
        {
            using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOKICONN"].ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                foreach (ItemAttribute item in attributesList)
                {
                    con.Execute("update oe_cnvwrk set cwr_response = ?, cwr_uom = ? where cwr_genero = ? and cwr_line = ?", 
                        new { cwr_response = item.cwr_response, cwr_uom = item.cwr_uom, cwr_genero = item.cwr_genero, cwr_line = item.cwr_line });
                }
                con.Close();
                return "success";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return x.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to skip spelling out each variable and simply reference the object? Or a better way to approach this period? Dapper allows for dynamically creating an object with a query, and for populating the values of a pre-defined object, but for updating an existing object I'm not finding any documentation or examples. With a larger object that becomes a bit of a pain, as does maintenance if the table and object need to be changed.

Comment: just wondering since I don' know Informix but looking at the `foreach` code should this foreach (ItemAttribute` be replaced with 
`foreach(var item in attributesList)` just currious or `foreach( string s in attributesList)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

```
using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOKICONN"].ToString()))
{
    con.Execute("update oe_cnvwrk set cwr_response = ?cwr_response?, cwr_uom = ?cwr_uom? where cwr_genero = ?cwr_genero? and cwr_line = ?cwr_line?", attributesList);
    return "success";
}
```

Changes:

- no need to open/close the connection
- passes the sequence directly; no need to loop
- uses the special dapper `?foo?` syntax, which maps *named members* from the available data to positional SQL; this will be re-written to use positional `?` sql, but adding the expected parameters in the expected order

Comment: Good to know when I finally will have the time to put my hands on that Access pesky little project.

Comment: Nice! I tried that and it failed, but after updating it worked perfectly. That's a nice improvement over the foreach loop.

While not having to pass in the individual parameters is great, is there a way to avoid the "set cwr_response = ?cwr_response?" part as well? I'm thinking that any members whose names match fields in the specified table would update to the object values. Ideally all I would need to do is something like:

con.Execute("update oe_cnvwrk set ?values? where cwr_genero = ?cwr_genero? and cwr_line = ?cwr_line?", attributesList);

Comment: @Ben not in dapper "core". There is a contrib/rainbow project that does more things like this. I don't think it specifically supports that, but you could add it and submit a pull request...